# How to use Nice / Renice to all new processes in future?

Tags: apache2, nice

I want to set up a top priority to Apache2, but when I do it to currently running processes by renice command, it only works until the processes are ended, new users come to a website and niceness of new processes is reset back to zero.

How can I set up a negative niceness to any new apache2 processes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a possible [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you need to do this? What is Apache competing against for resources?

Comment: I have a website where people upload videos. It fires ffmpeg and ffmpeg takes all the resources spiking the CPU to 100%. Since the videos are often large (200+ mb), and cpu is rather slow, I do not mind working it on full 100% for a longer time, but I want website to be responsive enough. Now, when 5 - 10 people upload a video, it completelly destroys the server and all it is doing is encoding ffmpeg.

Comment: Perhaps the mechanism of firing ffmpeg jobs could be adapted to raise their niceness?

Comment: Well it is actually php which fires ffmpeg, so I should re-write the module somehow to lower the niceness of ffmpeg processes? They are fired on cron each few minutes

Comment: Yes, but RAISE the niceness (positive values). You want ffmpeg to be nicer and cede resources to everything else. Example command to start ffmpeg at a high nice level: `nice -n 15 ffmpeg blah blah blah`

Comment: Ah okay, I will try to do that. Thanks a lot for your help!